# Rails Elastic Beanstalk - No Such File or Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rails app, deployed using Elastic Beanstalk.  I want to use ffmpeg to get information about audio files, which are stored on S3, and am using the streamio-ffmpeg gem to make this a little easier.

I have installed ffmpeg on the EC2 instance, which is working fine when SSH-ing into the instance, and have everything working absolutely fine locally.  I'm basically downloading the file from S3, and storing it in the /tmp folder, then calling on that through the streamio-ffmpeg gem.

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(
:access_key_id => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
:secret_access_key => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])
object = s3.buckets[ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]].objects[CGI::unescape(self.url)]

tempname = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(DateTime.now.to_s) + "." + self.file_format
File.open(Rails.root.to_s + '/tmp/' + tempname, 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(object.read)
end

dl = Rails.root.to_s + '/tmp/' + tempname
audio = FFMPEG::Movie.new(dl)
```

The error occurs on that final line, when I get this error

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - ffmpeg -i /var/app/current/tmp/46951a3d16abb2e5fcf1da9e4cf8e0f3.flac)
```

Am I doing something stupid here?  When I SSH into the instance, the file is where it should be, and when I run that line in the command line, it runs absolutely fine.

UPDATE
I'm no expert on Linux, but running ls -l in the tmp directory gives me

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 webapp webapp 26445358 Apr  9 13:07 90da56d83822a0bf716b5dfaae27844b.wav
```

Are these permissions restrictive?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Not sure, why the problem is occurring, it seems OK. Can you check permission ?

Comment: I've added the file permissions to the post

Comment: Ok, so I think I've narrowed this down to the webapp user on the instance not being able to use ffmpeg. Any ideas as to how I can fix that?

Comment: The permissions on the .wav file look fine; also check the permissions on the tmp/ directory that contains it. A couple more things to try and troubleshoot: execute the unix command as webapp: 'sudo -u webapp ffmpeg -i /var/app/...'  Also, test running the FFMPEG::Movie.new(dl) line from the rails console, running as the webapp user.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would only construct the full path once and refer to it the same way in both places, so that there's no chance of them getting out of sync if you ever change how the path is put together. It should also make it easier to read.

```
tempname = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(DateTime.now.to_s) + "." + self.file_format
temppath = Rails.root.join('tmp', tempname)
File.open(temppath, 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(object.read)
end

audio = FFMPEG::Movie.new(temppath)
```

If it still isn't found, the only thing I can think of is some sort of race condition, if it isn't quite visible to the OS right after it's been closed. Seems unlikely though.

Comment: Fair point on constructing the path once. I'm still getting the same error though...